# MySQL query results return unexpected data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query for a custom report that is supposed to return data for clients that match five criteria based on loan repayment types within a specified date range. The criteria are **`Salary Deduction`**, **`Bank Standing Order`**, **`Self-Pay`**, **`Post Dated Cheques`** and **`Bank Debit`**. The results should return a count of the number of clients from each criteria specified. However, that is not the results I am currently getting; these queries are being tested against this software, [Mambu](http://www.mambu.com/). The results depend on a **`customfield`** and **`customfieldvalue`** (*which specifies the repayment type to use*) columns. This is how I expect my desired results should look:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| LoanProduct           | RepaymentType    | Clients |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| JUMPSTART LOAN WEEKLY | Self-Pay         | 35      |
------------------------------------------------------
| PAYDAY LOAN MONTHLY   | Salary Deduction | 5       |
------------------------------------------------------
| MICRO-BIZ LOAN        | Bank Debit       | 26      |
------------------------------------------------------
| PAYDAY LOAN WEEKLY    | Self-Pay         | 1       |

  .......
and so on ...
```

Solutions that I've tries so far:

**QUERY #1:**
For this query I'm just trying to get back all the clients without a count for a specific repayment type; it works for that scenario.

```
SELECT CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME) AS Client, 
    CONCAT(user.FIRSTNAME, ' ', user.LASTNAME) AS Originator, 
    loanproduct.PRODUCTNAME AS LoanProduct, customfieldvalue.VALUE AS RepaymentType
FROM client, user, customfieldvalue, loanaccount
INNER JOIN loanproduct ON loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY 
WHERE client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY 
    AND loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY
    AND customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Bank Debit"
    AND loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
GROUP BY user.LASTNAME, client.LASTNAME
```

**QUERY #1.1**
Adding an `OR` to the above produces no results:

```
SELECT CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME) AS Client, 
    CONCAT(user.FIRSTNAME, ' ', user.LASTNAME) AS Originator, 
    loanproduct.PRODUCTNAME AS LoanProduct, customfieldvalue.VALUE AS RepaymentType
FROM client, user, customfieldvalue, loanaccount
INNER JOIN loanproduct ON loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY 
WHERE client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY 
    AND loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY
    AND customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Bank Debit" OR customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Self-Pay"
    AND loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
GROUP BY user.LASTNAME, client.LASTNAME
```

**QUERY #2**
I even tried doing this using a `CASE` statement, but it only returns all the rows for `Clients` as `NULL` and takes ~12.1 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT
    loanproduct.PRODUCTNAME AS LoanProduct, customfieldvalue.VALUE AS RepaymentType,
    CASE
       WHEN customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Salary Deduction" THEN COUNT(CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME))
       WHEN customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Bank Standing Order" THEN COUNT(CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME))
       WHEN customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Self-Pay" THEN COUNT(CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME))
       WHEN customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Post Dated Cheques" THEN COUNT(CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME))
       WHEN customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Bank Debit" THEN COUNT(CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME))
    END AS Clients
FROM client, user, customfieldvalue, loanaccount
INNER JOIN loanproduct ON  loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY
WHERE client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY
    AND loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY
    AND loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
GROUP BY user.LASTNAME, client.LASTNAME
```

What am I doing wrong here, which is preventing me from getting my desired results? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For query 2, you need to add parentheses, or use `in` syntax:

```
AND customfieldvalue.VALUE in ('Bank Debit', 'Self-Pay')
```

As important as getting the where syntax right is fixing the `join` syntax in the `from` clause:

```
FROM client join
     user
     on client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY join
     loanproduct
     ON loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY and
        loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY CROSS JOIN
    customFieldValue
where loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31" and
      customfieldvalue.value in ('Bank Debit')
```

Gosh, you would see right away that something is probably wrong.  You usually don't want to be cross joining tables in a well designed data warehouse.  How is CustomFieldValue connected to the other tables?

Comment: The CustomFieldValue provides the users with the flexibility to add certain field to their forms on the fly. In the data dictionary the diagram shows them a detached from the other tables, so any form can have a CustomField.

Comment: And the custom value is not connected to a client or to a loan or to any other entity?

Comment: It is connected to the `client` table.

Answer (score 0):

Quotations (order of operations) are TOTALLY important here, you're missing them, and that's the issue.

```
SELECT CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME) AS Client, 
    CONCAT(user.FIRSTNAME, ' ', user.LASTNAME) AS Originator, 
    loanproduct.PRODUCTNAME AS LoanProduct, customfieldvalue.VALUE AS RepaymentType
FROM client, user, customfieldvalue, loanaccount
INNER JOIN loanproduct ON loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY 
WHERE client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY 
    AND loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY
    AND (customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Bank Debit" OR customfieldvalue.VALUE = "Self-Pay")
    AND loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
GROUP BY user.LASTNAME, client.LASTNAME
```

An alternative would be using "IN()"

```
SELECT CONCAT(client.FIRSTNAME, ' ', client.LASTNAME) AS Client, 
    CONCAT(user.FIRSTNAME, ' ', user.LASTNAME) AS Originator, 
    loanproduct.PRODUCTNAME AS LoanProduct, customfieldvalue.VALUE AS RepaymentType
FROM client, user, customfieldvalue, loanaccount
INNER JOIN loanproduct ON loanaccount.PRODUCTTYPEKEY = loanproduct.ENCODEDKEY 
WHERE client.ASSIGNEDUSERKEY = user.ENCODEDKEY 
    AND loanaccount.ACCOUNTHOLDERKEY = client.ENCODEDKEY
    AND customfieldvalue.VALUE IN("Bank Debit", "Self-Pay")
    AND loanaccount.DISBURSEMENTDATE BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2013-01-31"
GROUP BY user.LASTNAME, client.LASTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of items stand out. 
First it appears you are attempting to join 4 files but only have 1 join defined - it sometimes helps to add files 1 at a time when building a complex join.

Also you are using GROUP BY without aggregating anything - are you sure that is what you are intending? If you want a count you could use `count(*)` and then all other columns need to be included on the GROUP BY Clause.

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended. I initially had the `count(*)`, but I removed it to display the actual client's name, so I could verify the data that I'm getting back with the output from the software.